# Fractional Part integral $I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$

Tags: analysis

Let $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y.$$ When I tried computing the integral I seem to be getting a different answer to Wolramaplha, and can't find a similar integral anywhere on MSE or the internet.

Here's how I did it $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1} \left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\}\mathrm{d}y\right)\mathrm{d}x$$, Lets evaluate, (Note: $0<x<1$) $$I_1=\int_{0}^{1} \left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\}\mathrm{d}y =\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{xy-\lfloor xy \rfloor  }{y^2}\mathrm{d}y=x(1-\gamma)$$

Therefore $I=\frac{(1-\gamma)}{2}$.

However Wolfram gives $I= 0.458868$.

Can someone help, or if my answer is wrong then provide a solution.

Comment: I suppose that the numerical integration is not the easiest one.

Comment: Use the substitution $(x, y) = (t y, y)$ where $0 < y < 1$ when $0<t<1$ and $0 < y < 1 / t$ when $ 1 < t$. Then integrate first with respect to $y$, then with respect to $t$ on intervals $[n, n+1)$.

Comment: [*This*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199246/integral-of-fractionalpart-function/2199439#2199439) might be relevant.

Comment: How did you get $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{xy-\lfloor xy \rfloor  }{y^2}\mathrm{d}y=x(1-\gamma)$? The mistake seems to be at that point

Comment: The middle expression for $I_1$ is not obvious to me. Please, see my answer below, which I believe is straight forward.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1567597/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do the things exactly:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=
\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{0}^{1} \left\{\frac xy\right\}\; dy
\\
&\qquad\text{(Substitution: $y=x/z$)}
\\
&=
\int_0^1dx \int_x^\infty \left\{ z\right\}\;\frac x{z^2}\; dz
\\
&=
\int_0^1x\; dx 
\left(\ 
\int_x^1 \left\{ z\right\}\;\frac {dz}{z^2}
+
\int_1^\infty \left\{ z\right\}\;\frac {dz}{z^2}
\
\right)
\\
&=
\int_0^1x\; dx 
\underbrace{\int_x^1 z\;\frac {dz}{z^2}}_{-\log x}
\qquad +\qquad
\underbrace{\int_0^1x\; dx}_{=1/2} 
\sum_{n\ge 1}\int_n^{n+1} \{z\}\;\frac {dz}{z^2}
\\
&=
\frac 14
+
\frac 12\sum_{n\ge 1}
\int_0^1 t\;\frac {dt}{(n+t)^2}
\\
&=
\frac 14
+
\frac 12\sum_{n\ge 1}
\left(\log\frac{n+1}n-\frac 1{n+1}\right)
\\
&=
\frac 14
+
\frac 12\lim_{N\to\infty}
\left(\log(N+1)-\frac 12-\frac 13-\dots-\frac1{N+1}\right)
\\
&=
\frac 14
+
\frac 12\left(1-\gamma\right)
\\
&=
\frac 14(3-2\gamma)
\\
&\approx
0.46139216754923\dots
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Computer checks:

Sage gives the numerical value for $(3-2\gamma)/4$:

```
sage: (3 - 2*euler_gamma.n())/4
0.461392167549234
```

---

Pari/gp has a better numerical integration, so i tried...

```
? \p 300
   realprecision = 308 significant digits (300 digits displayed)
? intnum(x=0, 1, intnum(y=0.00001, 1, frac(x/y)))
%20 = 0.4632302758838776079638791660602840407334814843635587641353594901119...
```

(Last result was manually truncated.)

```
? (3 - 2*Euler)/4
%22 = 0.4613921675492335696967439549587987844789203320300382005971163825575...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different way of doing this. I assume the unstated fact, apparently obvious, that $\left\{\frac xy\right\}$ is the fractional part of $\frac xy$.
Then
\begin{aligned}
I&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\left\{\frac xy\right\}dxdy=\int_0^1\left[
\int_x^1\frac xy dy+\int_0^x\left\{\frac xy\right\}dy\right]dx\\
&=-\int_0^1 x\ln x dx+\int_0^1\int_0^x\left\{\frac xy\right\}dydx
\end{aligned}
We now divide the interval from 0 to $x$ in the intervals $\frac x{n+1}<y<\frac xn$. Hence, in this interval, we have $n<\frac xy<n+1$. Therefore,
in each such interval, $\frac xy=n+\left\{\frac xy\right\}$.
Thus, we obtain
\begin{aligned}
I &=\frac14+\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{\frac x{n+1}}^{\frac xn}\left\{\frac xy\right\}dydx=\frac14+\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{\frac x{n+1}}^{\frac xn}\left[\frac xy-n\right]dydx\\
&=\frac 14+\int_0^1xdx\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\ln\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)-n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac 14+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\frac1{n+1}\right]
\end{aligned}
This is the same result obtained by @dan_fulea